# What is the purpose of the "Menu language" widget?

Tags: i18n-l10n, 10

When the Content Translation module is enabled, a "Menu language" widget appears in the form for editing menus:

[image]

What is the purpose of this widget?  What does it do?

It does not seem to affect my site at all when I change the dropdown to a different language, or to "Not specified" or "Not applicable."

Answer (score 1):

This is the original language for the label and the description. After saving the menu in the original language you can click on the tab above (admin/structure/menu/manage/main/translate) and translate the two text fields into other languages.

Comment: I tried visiting /structure/menu/manage/main/translate and also /admin/structure/menu/manage/main/translate and I get "page not found."  So I am wondering if there are cases when the Menu Language widget is totally irrelevant to the site but Drupal still presents the widget.

Comment: You could use the tab "Translate menu" directly above the screenshot in the question. This is the standard translation for all config objects and is not menu-specific. I don't know whether the translation of the two fields is relevant to your site, but it looks better in UI if the two fields are translated.

Comment: "original language for the label and the description."  Do you mean the Title and Administrative Summary of the menu itself?  If so, for clarity's sake, should we edit your answer to use the same language used in the UI?

Comment: Yes, but when you translate the fields they are called label and description, which is also used to store the fields in config.